# htaccess rewrite to remove part of a url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't find the answer so I'm hopeful someone can help.

How do I change the url in this example using .htaccess:

```
domain.com/product/sku/a=code&rss=1
```

to

```
domain.com/product/sku/a=code
```

(I just need the `&rss=1` removed)

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|^)rss=[0-9]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but for some reason it's not working for me.  If you want to see for yourself, you can go to http://adult.toysblog.co and click on the product photos or the link that says "View Item" and they both still have the &rss=1.

Comment: @user1667113 are you sure you have the rules before any other rules that you mmay have in your htaccess file? When I put the above rules in a blank htaccess file on a newly installed apache server, it removes the `rss=1` from the URL.

Comment: Thanks again, Jon Lin.  No, I have that code last.  I'll move it to the top and report back.

Comment: Changing the placement of the code didn't help.  Could there be a separate issue in that the posts in that blog I included above are being posted from an rss feed?  Even if that is a separate issue, I'm sure there's a way to remove the &rss=1, it just may require something besides .htaccess.

Comment: @DocJohnson The rules aren't being applied for some reason, I don't have enough information to guess why.